# Kuka LWR teleoperation with phantom omni

Tags: ros, kuka, teleop

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Anyone used Phantom Omni on Kuka LWR Robot or on another industrial Robot?
I need information for teleoperate a Kuka LWR robot with Phantom Omni haptic.
I use ROS Fuerte and sometimes ROS Electric, also used the arm navigation service and inverse kinematics.
The problem is that the arm moves in excess and the orientation of joints is not correct. How should associate the tf of Phantom Omni and the tf of Robot?
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41911/kuka-lwr-teleoperation-with-phantom-omni/) by [Jose Luis](https://answers.ros.org/users/3057/jose-luis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 375 on 2012-08-21

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To answer your last question, have you gone through the tf tutorials?

> [www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials)

Also, this related question might be helpful:

> answers.ros.org/question/9094/has-anyone-used-any-haptic-devices-in-conjunction-with-ros/

---

Originally posted by [isura](https://answers.ros.org/users/1583/isura/) with karma: 403 on 2012-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1